# Rails can't find JSON gem but bundle install can?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, bundle, osx-elcapitan

Just upgraded to OS X El Capitan and trying to create a new rails app for the first time since the upgrade. After a few hurdles (and alot of googling) I finally got the app created. When I try to create a new model using `rails g model Mymodel` I get this error:

```
    Could not find json-1.8.3 in any of the sources
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run `bundle install` I get this:

```
    Resolving dependencies...
    Using rake 10.4.2
    Using i18n 0.7.0
    Using json 1.8.3
    ...
    Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.
    Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

When I run `bundle show json` I get:

```
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3
```

I know the basics of the rails setup but any troubleshooting like this has always been over my head. I imagine the solution is probably simple but by google searches haven't given me anything. Maybe I'm just not searching with the correct phrasing. Anyhow, does anyone have any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Much appreciation!

**UPDATE:**

When I try to uninstall so I can reinstall I get the error:

```
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "json" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The only thing I'm doing different than other new apps I've created is adding bootstrap. In my Gemfile I have:

```
    gem 'bootstrap-sass'
    gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

I thought maybe one of them was causing the issue so I started by removing the autoprefixer gem from my Gemfile. I then ran the `g model` command and I got this error:

```
    Could not find autoprefixer-rails-6.1.0.1 in any of the sources
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

which is the same as the previous error but with a different gem. So, I put the gem back into the Gemfile and I'm still getting that error. I have no idea what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: You can unistall the gem and install it again.

Comment: Does running `bundle exec rails g model Mymodel` fix the problem?

Comment: Is there a chance that you don't have the json gem installed in the development group? That's the only time I have seen this specific error.  It shouldn't even be in the Gemfile unless you want to pin a particular version.  Max's comment is also a good thing to try

Comment: @max - It does not fix the problem.

Comment: @joem - It's not listed in the Gemfile. I'm not super knowledgeable in this sort of thing so can you explain the development group thing and how I can check it?

Comment: @JosiahPalmer the json gem shouldn't be in the GemFile normally, so that is not the problem in this case.  Groups in the gemfile define the rails environment in which gems should be loaded.  For example, you would add rspec to the test environment only so that it does not get loaded in production.  I have had gems go missing that way, but the json gem is loaded by default and should not be in the gemfile under normal circumstances.  I thought that if it had found it's way in there that it could be a problem.  sounds like not though

Comment: @JosiahPalmer can you start the rails server or console?  You could try explicitly adding it to the Gemfile.  Near the top of the file, just add the line: "gem 'json'" and see what happens

Comment: @joem - I cannot start either. I get the same error. I just tried a few things and referenced it in "Update 2" up there. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94642/discussion-between-joem-and-josiah-palmer).